# rewrite componentDidUpdate(prevProps) into a hook with redux

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux

I would like to rewrite this life cycle method into a hook but it does'nt work as expected. 
when the componentdidmounted, if the user id exists in the local storage,the user is connected and his name is displayed in the navbar. And when he disconnects and reconnects his name is displayed in the navbar.
So i am trying to convert this class Component with hooks, when the username changes nothing is displayed in the navbar so i have to refresh the page and that way his name is displayed

The real problem is the componentDidUpdate
how can i get and compare the prevProps with hooks

The class Component

```
const mapStateToProps = state => ({
        ...state.authReducer
    }
);
const mapDispatchToProps = {
    userSetId,
    userProfilFetch,
    userLogout
};

class App extends React.Component {

    componentDidMount() {
        const userId = window.localStorage.getItem("userId");
        const {userSetId} = this.props;
        if (userId) {
            userSetId(userId)
        }
    }

    componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState, snapshot) {
        const {userId, userProfilFetch, userData} = this.props; //from redux store
        if(prevProps.userId !== userId && userId !== null && userData === null){
            userProfilFetch(userId);

        }
    }
    render() {
    return (
        <div>
          <Router>
              <Routes/>
          </Router>
        </div>
    );
  }
}
export default connect(mapStateToProps,mapDispatchToProps)(App);
```

With hooks

```
const App = (props) => {
    const dispatch = useDispatch();
    const userData = useSelector(state => state.authReducer[props.userData]);
    const userId = window.localStorage.getItem("userId");


    useEffect(()=> {
        if(!userId){
            dispatch(userSetId(userId))
            dispatch(userProfilFetch(userId))
        }
    }, [userData, userId, dispatch])

    return(
        <Router>
            <Routes/>
        </Router>
    )
};

export default App;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

now i  resolve it, i made this

```
const App = props => {
    const userId = window.localStorage.getItem("userId");
    const dispatch = useDispatch();
    const userData = useSelector(state=> state.authReducer[props.userData]);
    const isAuthenticated = useSelector(state=> state.authReducer.isAuthenticated);

    useEffect(()=> {
        if(userId){
            dispatch(userSetId(userId))
            dispatch(userProfilFetch(userId))
        }
    }, [userId])
    return(
        <div>
            <Router>
                <Routes/>
            </Router>
        </div>
    )
};
```

Answer (score 2):

[How to get the previous props or state?](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-faq.html#how-to-get-the-previous-props-or-state)

Basically create a custom hook to cache a value:

```
const usePrevious = value => {
  const ref = useRef();
  useEffect(() => {
    ref.current = value;
  });
  return ref.current;
}
```

Usage:

```
const App = (props) => {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const userData = useSelector(state => state.authReducer[props.userData]);
  const userId = window.localStorage.getItem("userId");

  // get previous id and cache current id
  const prevUserId = usePrevious(userId);

  useEffect(()=> {
    if(!userId){
      dispatch(userSetId(userId))
      dispatch(userProfileFetch(userId))
    }

    // do comparison with previous and current id value
    if (prevUserId !== userId) {
      dispatch(userProfileFetch(userId));
    }
  }, [userData, userId, prevUserId, dispatch])

  return(
    <Router>
      <Routes/>
    </Router>
  )
};
```

FYI: You may want to refactor the code a bit to do the fetch from local storage in an effect hook that runs only on mount. If I understand your app flow correctly it would look something like this:

```
const App = (props) => {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const { userId } = useSelector(state => state.authReducer[props.userData]);

  useEffect(() => {
    const userId = window.localStorage.getItem("userId");
    userId && dispatch(userSetId(userId));
  }, []);

  // get previous id and cache current id
  const prevUserId = usePrevious(userId);

  useEffect(()=> {
    if(!userId){
      dispatch(userSetId(userId))
      dispatch(userProfileFetch(userId))
    }

    // do comparison with previous and current id value
    if (prevUserId !== userId) {
      dispatch(userProfileFetch(userId));
    }
  }, [userId, prevUserId, dispatch])

  return(
    <Router>
      <Routes/>
    </Router>
  )
};
```

Comment: Only passing userData as props to useEffect hook doesn't solve the problem, avoiding the creation of a custom hook? https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html (Tip: Optimizing Performance by Skipping Effects)

Comment: @Drew Reese I tried to implement the solution that you've proposed but it does not work, it always reproduces the initial behavior.
I solved it by placing userId alone in the dependency array

Comment: @Beloved Ah, so you didn't actually need to compare to the previous value. Good job.